# Imports failing for pylint

Tags: django, pylint, import

I'm testing my project using pylint and currently getting fatal error when importing the internal apps into the project using.

According to pylint, the import should be something like `from <appname>.models import ...`
as opposed to what I currently have: `from <projectname>.<appname>.models import`  My problem is that when I use the recommended style, the project can't find/import the app.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apps are not in the python path.

Seems like you have a folder for apps, like `apps/registration`, `apps/contact_form` etc. and your manage.py is in the folder on top of that one, which has just the project folder.

`manage.py` does some "magic" by putting all the apps into the python path before starting the server.

If you have custom folder structure, you should edit the `manage.py` to include your custom apps folder in the python path, preferably as the first element of the python path.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, asI don't have a folder for apps.  I don't know if this helps but the problem only occurs when running the project using mod_wsgi...using the inbuilt Django dev server, everything is good

Comment: There you go. You need to customize the sys.path inside your mod_wsgi file.

Comment: Thnx Lakshman...I figured that bit on the mod_wsgi after posting the first comment...made the changes and it works like a charm